# Ayuda!, como puedo acceder al valor del objecto hijo. "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys{...} I

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, javascript-objeto

Hola como va tengo un par de dudas!, como puedo acceder a la herencia de un objeto, le muestro:

Yo ando intentando solamente coger el dato de NewConfirmed, que tiene como padre a "Global" 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ahora solo puedo coger el dato "Date"

```js
stats = () => {
    const { dataCovid } = this.props;
    if (this.props.loader) {
      return (/**/ );
    }
    return (
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-md-4'>
          <div className='card stat-card'>
            <div className='card-body'>
              <h5 className='card-title'>Total de Nuevos    Contagio:</h5>
              <h2 className='float-right'> {dataCovid.Date}</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Ahora bien, si intento llamar datacovid.Global, en consola me sale lo siguiente:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {NewConfirmed, TotalConfirmed, NewDeaths, TotalDeaths, NewRecovered, TotalRecovered})
```

y si le asigno el valor de NewConfimed me arroja

```
 TypeError: dataCovid.Global is undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {NewConfirmed, TotalConfirmed, NewDeaths, TotalDeaths, NewRecovered, TotalRecovered})
```

Esto error te sale porque estas intentando renderear un objeto(`datacovid.Global`) y eso no se puede, tienes que iterar y mostrar el valor de cada uno o los que quieras, de los campos que haya en el objeto, esto si es un objeto o arreglo, pero si es un objeto y solo quieres mostrar un campo, podrias acceder director a esa propiedad del objeto.

Se me ocurre que puedes hacer una validacion solo para verificar que `datacovid.Global` exista y si es asi acceder a `NewConfirmed`

```
return (
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-md-4'>
          <div className='card stat-card'>
            <div className='card-body'>
              <h5 className='card-title'>Total de Nuevos    Contagio:</h5>
              <h2 className='float-right'>{datacovid.Global && datacovid.Global.NewConfirmed}</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, creeeme que me puse a tduair todo las herencia de js.

Comment: Tengo una pregunta, supongamos que newConfirmed tiene un hijo, como puedo acceder al hijo? (nieto de global por llamarlo asi)

Comment: Pues igual que como se hizo para acceder a Newconfirmed, datacovid.Global.NewConfirmed.otrapropiedad. Igual podrías validar que newConfirmed tenga algo para así acceder a su hijo